# Styling numbered chapter and unnumbered chapter in Table of Content using KOMA Script (scrbook)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

I need to style the Numbered and Unnumbered Chapter in my Table of Contents, using `scrbook`, so that:

1. The Numbered Chapter is in uppercase, in the form of `chapterprefix` em-dash `chaptertitle`, e.g. CHAPTER 1 --- FOO.
2. One of the Unnumbered Chapter, the Abstract (in English), is italicised.

My MWE

```
%% Preamble %%
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,chapterprefix=true,headings=twolinechapter,oneside,]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

% Style Table of Content.
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\chapapp\ #1}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
   tocentrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumberformat,
   tocnumwidth= 5em,
]{chapter}

\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}

\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
 \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
  {\addtocontents{toc}
   {\protect\begingroup
    \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}%
    \protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}%
   }%
   \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
  }
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}%
}

%% Document Parts %%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{ABSTRAK} % Abstract in language other than English
\lipsum[1]
\addchap{ABSTRACT} % Abstract in English, must be shown italicised in ToC
\lipsum[2]
\mainmatter
\addchap{SOMESTUFFS}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{FOO}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

I do appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I do not really understand the sense of changing the formatting of only one ToC entry. Nevertheless you can use class option `headings=optiontotocandhead` and `\addchap[tocentry=\protect\textit{ABSTRACT}]{ABSTRACT}` or you can define a new section command using `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` and set option `tocentryformat` to `\textit`. The last solution would be more nice.

Comment: I do not really understand either, but the requirement says so. I assume because there are two versions of abstracts, one in language other than English (the main language of the entire document), and another is the translation to English. The English title of Abstract, then, is italicised to distinguish it as the foreign language -- although the entire text of the abstract in Engish is strangely not italicised. As for your suggestion, how would I do `\DeclareNewSectionCommand`? I my original MWE, I already declared one for {chapter}. I am confused to be honest.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I tried class option `headings=optiontotocandhead` (changed the `headings=twolinechapter` in my original MWE with class option you suggested) and `\addchap[tocentry=\protect\textit{ABSTRACT}]{ABSTRACT}`. That does not work. The entry for ABSTRACT in ToC now shows tocentry=ABSTRACT . . . . . . . . . . (iii). I have no idea on how to define `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` and set option `tocentryformat` to `\textit`.

Comment: My mistake: The `\addchap` command has to be: `\addchap[tocentry=\normalfont\textit{ABSTRACT}]{ABSTRACT}` (without `\protect` but with additional `\normalfont` because there is no bold italic sans serif font `OT1/cmss/bx/it`). If you need bold italic sans serif, you need to use another font, e.g., `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}` or `\usepackage{lmodern}` (last one before `\usepackage{mathptmx}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
\usepackage{xpatch}% needed to path \addchaptertocentry

% Style Table of Content.
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\MakeUppercase\chapapp\ #1\kern 0.25em---\kern 0.25em}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {\IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocontents{toc}
     {\protect\begingroup
      \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}%
      \protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}%
     }%
     \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
    }
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\protect\chapterentrynumberformat{#1}\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
```

With the suggestion of @Schweinebacke (see his comments to the question) and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,a4paper,
  chapterprefix=true,% chapterprefixline does the same
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc,% <- added
  oneside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{xpatch}% needed to path \addchaptertocentry

% Style Table of Content.
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\MakeUppercase\chapapp\ #1\kern 0.25em---\kern 0.25em}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {\IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocontents{toc}
     {\protect\begingroup
      \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}%
      \protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}%
     }%
     \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
    }
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\protect\chapterentrynumberformat{#1}\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

%% Document Parts %%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{ABSTRAK} % Abstract in language other than English
\lipsum[1]
\addchap[tocentry=\textit{ABSTRACT}]{ABSTRACT} % Abstract in English, must be shown italicised in ToC
\lipsum[2]
\mainmatter
\addchap{SOMESTUFFS}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{FOO}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[4]
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Chapter with two digit number}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

**Update**

If you are loading package `hyperref` use command `\texorpdfstring` to avoid the `\MakeUppercase ...ppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings` error:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,a4paper,
  chapterprefix=true,% chapterprefixline does the same
  headings=optiontoheadandtoc,% <- added
  oneside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{xpatch}% needed to path \addchaptertocentry
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Style Table of Content.
\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\MakeUppercase\chapapp\ #1\kern 0.25em---\kern 0.25em}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {\IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocontents{toc}
     {\protect\begingroup
      \protect\setkomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{}%
      \protect\KOMAoptions{chapterentrydots}%
     }%
     \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
     \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}%
    }
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\chapterentrynumberformat{#1}\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

%% Document Parts %%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{ABSTRAK} % Abstract in language other than English
\lipsum[1]
\addchap[tocentry=\textit{ABSTRACT}]{ABSTRACT} % Abstract in English, must be shown italicised in ToC
\lipsum[2]
\mainmatter
\addchap{SOMESTUFFS}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{FOO}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[4]
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Chapter with two digit number}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, esp. when there are two digit chapters. No need to fiddle with `tocnumwidth` like my previous partial answer. Thank youuu... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to my own question, i.e., to add the em-dash between the `chapterprefix` and `chaptertitle` in Numbered Chapter entries in ToC, and make the `chapterprefix` uppercase.

In my original MWE

```
% Style Table of Content.
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\chapapp\ #1}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
   tocentrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumberformat,
   tocnumwidth= 5em,
]{chapter}
```

I append `\MakeUppercase` before `\chapapp` (that prints "Chapter"), add the em-dash with some hspace before and after the em-dash. Then I adjust the `tocnumwidth` attribute of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`so that the `chaptertitle` does not overlaps with the em-dash.
The MWE now reads

```
% Style Table of Content.
\newcommand\chapterentrynumberformat[1]{\MakeUppercase\chapapp\ #1\kern 0.25em---\kern 0.25em}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
   tocentrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumberformat,
   tocnumwidth= 7.5em,
]{chapter}
```

I am still looking for solution on how to italicise one of the Unnumbered Chapters (i.e. the ABSTRACT).